# Kth number whose all digits are even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As my title says.. what is the formula for kth number whose all digits are even (i.e digits can take 0,2,4,6,8)?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the sequence of numbers all of whose digits are even is equivalent to computing in base $5$ with the digits $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$.  Consequently, express $k$ in the base $5$ and then (in base $10$) double all its digits.  For instance, the $1000^\text{th}$ such number is $1000_{10} = 13000_5 \rightarrow 26000_{10}$.

Is this an inadequate formulation?

Comment: Thanks dude.. I got it now :)

Comment: that was on the tip of my tongue, have a +1 .